# Step down converter PCB

Tags: module

Is one side of R050 connected to OUT- ?
To nut for the acrylic housing would bridge the little gap there - is that a problem?
Thx.
[image]

Comment: Measure it with a multimeter. Seems like beeing connected though.

Comment: Placing components this close to screw terminals is a mistake, no matter what. The screw will put force on the solder joint which will crack the solder at some point. Worst case, it might even crack the component.

Comment: OUT- is not connected to that large copper plane (notice the open ring around it - unlike OUT+).

Comment: @brhans, the "open ring" around `OUT−` you are talking about (if I understand correctly) is nothing but a keep-out area of the solder mask, which I think is also present at `OUT+`...

Comment: @aschipfl, OUT+ and OUT- are clearly very different. OUT+ is connected to its surrounding copper plane, while OUT- is not. A lack of solder-mask would show as the same color as that surrounding the mounting hole in the corner, which is clearly different to the ring surrounding OUT-.

Comment: Sure looks connected. Also kinda looks like someone removed the solder mask with a knife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One side of the resistor is connected to the mounting pad.  Bridging the gap electrically would not be a problem as they are already connected electrically.  Bridging to the pin above the mounting hole may be a problem as the pin is not connected to the resistor on this side of the board.

Mechanically though this will eventually become a problem, cracking solder, perhaps cracking the resistor.

Two things you might consider:

1. Replacing the resistor with a leaded resistor and gluing the resistor to the board some distance away from OUT-.  This may prevent cracking of the resistor.
2. You might want to use a nylon washer to make a softer connection to the mounting hole.  This may ease some of the mechanical stress to the solder pad.

[image]

It *may* have been the intent of the layout to use the mounting hole as a way of wicking heat from the resistor to the structure mechanically connected at that mounting hole.  As stated elsewhere this has been designed poorly.

Always keep in mind with these evaluation boards that they are not designed for production applications.  They are designed solely for evaluating the performance of the electronics on the board.  And users are expected to produce their own board design that makes sense in their application.

Comment: There is no evidence that OUT- is connected to either side of "R050". The left end of the resistor is connected to something on the other side of the board via the plating in the mounting hole (which is itself a bad idea!).

Comment: If the "OUT-" silkscreen is indicating the pin then no.  If it is indicating the hole then yes.  Agreed that the pin is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the only connection to the left side of "R050" is via the plating in the large hole in the corner of the board.

Therefore, this hole should not be used for mechanical support at all. Screw threads could easily damage the plating and break the circuit.

---

Furthermore, different mounting holes are connected to different circuit nodes, so all fasteners used for mounting must be insulated from the board — use nylon hardware or shoulder washers.

For all of these reasons, plus the ones mentioned by others, this is a very poor PCB design.